# Setting hi works from ex mode but not from vimdc

Tags: vim, macvim

If I execute this from ex mode than my conceals are highlighted correctly:

```
:hi Conceal guibg=#262626 guifg=white
```

but if I place the same in my .vimrc file, nothing happens:

```
hi Conceal guibg=#262626 guifg=white
```

I know my .vimrc is being consulted because the font is set and all other stuff is working.

It seems that even this setting is ignored:

```
set conceallevel=0
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that's a bug: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/542
There's known workaround using ColorScheme autocmd as suggested in the issue. I'm using it myself ;-)